# Несколько конфигураций для io.github.resilience4j

Tags: java, spring-boot

Необходимо настроить переотправку в зависимости от ошибки.

Стандартная конфигурация работает для обеих ошибок

```
resilience4j:
  retry:
    configs:
      default:
        maxRetryAttempts: 3 # The maximum number of retry attempt
        waitDuration: 500ms # Initial interval between retry attempts
        enableExponentialBackoff: true #common strategy for increasing the delay between retry attempts
        exponentialBackoffMultiplier: 2 #Multiplier for the exponential backoff
        retryExceptions:
           - Exception1
           - Exception2
    instances:
      myService:
        baseConfig: default
```

в коде над методом

```
@Retry(name = "myService")
...
}{ catch (Exception1 | Exception2 e) {
```

но нужно чтобы число попыток для разных ошибок было разным.

Можно ли настроить несколько baseConfig для одного instances ?